# The meaning of 恥を言うようです

Tags: meaning

I can't make sense of the phrase:

> 恥を言うようですが、～

From the situation I infer it's the same as 言うのは恥ずかしいですが~, but I'm not certain.

- How can a person "say shame" or "tell shame" (恥を言う)?
- Why is よう attached here?
- Is it a single set phrase, or do other phrases follow the same pattern?

Comment: I'll be honest with you.  Dunno where you saw/heard the phrase, but the chances are you are not going to see/hear it again.

Comment: Before posting I googled and [there were some resuts](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E6%81%A5%E3%82%92%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C%22&oq=%22%E6%81%A5%E3%82%92%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C%22), [also](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=%22%E6%81%A5%E3%82%92%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C%22&oq=%22%E6%81%A5%E3%82%92%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C%22#q=%22%E6%81%A5%E3%82%92%E8%A8%80%E3%81%86%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%22) so it doesn't look like a simple mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 恥を言うようですが、～

I think the above phrase may be the short form of like:
- 恥**になること**を言うようですが、～ *It seems to tell something that is shameful, but* ...
or
- 恥**になるようなこと**を言うようですが、～ *It seems to tell something that seemed shameful, but* ...

that is similar to what you guess as 言うのは恥ずかしいですが~,

If you know a set phrase "恥を晒｛さら｝す literally *to expose shame*", "**恥を晒すようですが、～**" is similar to the given phrase.

恥をさらす means in my dictionary:
- bring disgrace on oneself
- bring shame on oneself
- disgrace oneself in public

---

### EDIT

> 恥を言うようですが、～

As l'électeur said that the questioner would never see or hear it again, I also thought that this phrase is not natural as it is. However, since the questioner answered to the comment that there were some examples of use before posting the question, I checked it on the Internet. As a result, they were a very few, but surely there were use examples.
Among a few examples I'll introduce the following one because I think it is somewhat natural Japanese.

> 両親はそのうち気付くから、と言うのですが本当に**身内の恥を言うようですが** 40過ぎてもいつも自分の事しか考えられない、いつも自分の行動や発言が原因なのに人に何か言われるとすぐ被害者になって泣き、挙句に逆恨み。

It is understood from this example that naturalness increases when "恥" in the phrase is limited with a modifier relating to "私 or 自分" or "家族" like:

- 私の恥を言うようですが
- 自分の恥を言うようですが
- 家族の恥を言うようですが

Even in these examples as well, adding the expression "恐縮｛きょうしゅく｝です" make them more natural.

- 私の恥を言うようで恐縮ですが
- 自分の恥を言うようで恐縮ですが
- 家族の恥を言うようで恐縮ですが

Also, replacing "言う" with "晒｛さら｝す" introduced earlier will make them sound very natural.

- 私の恥を晒すようですが
- 自分の恥を晒すようですが
- 家族の恥を晒すようですが
- 私の恥を晒すようで恐縮ですが
- 自分の恥を晒すようで恐縮ですが
- 家族の恥を晒すようで恐縮ですが

Comment: So よう is used here almost intrinsically as a part of apology? ～ようで恐縮ですが or ～ようで申し訳ございません? It's use is synonymous with がましい, right?

Comment: @marcraf:  (1)「よう」は「恥を言う」と断定｛だんてい｝するのを避｛さ｝けるためであって、"a part of apology"ではないと思います。英語が得意｛とくい｝でないですが、"It may sound like I'm telling my personal shame, but ..."のようなニュアンスだと思います。(2) 「がましい」とはかなりニュアンスが違うように思います。「がましい」は手許｛てもと｝の辞書｛じしょ｝によると「いかにも～のようすである」と言う意味｛いみ｝があり、「恥を言うようですが」の「よう」に 似｛に｝ていますが、「がましい」の 用例｛ようれい｝ としての「押｛お｝しつけがましい」「恩着｛おんき｝せがましい」「 晴｛は｝ れがましい」「烏滸｛おこ｝がましい」などを見ると「恥を言うようですが」の「よう」とはニュアンスが少し違うように思います。「恥を言う」は、「言わなくて 済{す} むなら本当｛ほんとう｝は言いたくないが恥を忍｛しの｝んで言う」というようなニュアンスですが、「がましい」を用いると、「言わなくても 良｛よ｝ いのに、わざわざ自分｛じぶん｝の恥を他人｛たにん｝に言う」ような 感｛かん｝ じがします。どうでしょうか。